# How to do theorems that require mutual recursion?

Tags: coq

I ran into a problem that required mutual recursion to solve. I could not do it in Coq, but I suspected that it might be possible in Agda and proved that is the case using two mutually recursive functions. I am not sure what exactly I should do to bring that solution back into Coq and Googling this problem has not turned up any solutions.

What are my options here?

To further motivate the question here is the Agda proof that I want to translate into Coq. It proves the functional equality between a tree walking and a flattened calculator.

The proof requires that `remove-from-stack` and `add-to-stack` call each other in a mutually recursive manner.

```
open import Data.Product
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.List
open import Data.List.Properties
open import Function

import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as Eq
open Eq using (_≡_; refl; cong; subst)
open Eq.≡-Reasoning

data Sinstr : Set where
  SPush : ℕ → Sinstr
  SPlus : Sinstr

data Aexp : Set where
  ANum : (n : ℕ) → Aexp
  APlus : Aexp → Aexp → Aexp

s-execute : List Sinstr → List ℕ → List ℕ
s-execute [] stack = stack
s-execute (SPush x ∷ prog) stack = s-execute prog (x ∷ stack)
s-execute (SPlus ∷ prog) (x1 ∷ x2 ∷ stack) = s-execute prog (x2 + x1 ∷ stack)
s-execute _ stack = stack

aeval : Aexp → ℕ
aeval (ANum n) = n
aeval (APlus a a₁) = aeval a + aeval a₁

s-compile : Aexp → List Sinstr
s-compile (ANum n) = [ SPush n ]
s-compile (APlus a a₁) = s-compile a ++ s-compile a₁ ++ [ SPlus ]

++-assoc⁴ : ∀ {T : Set} (a b c d : List T) → (a ++ b ++ c) ++ d ≡ a ++ b ++ c ++ d
++-assoc⁴ a b c d =
  begin
    ((a ++ b ++ c) ++ d)
  ≡⟨ ++-assoc a (b ++ c) d ⟩
    (a ++ (b ++ c) ++ d)
  ≡⟨ cong (a ++_) (++-assoc b c d) ⟩
    (a ++ b ++ c ++ d)
  ∎

remove-from-stack : ∀ {e2 stack x} e1 →
  s-execute (s-compile e1 ++ e2) stack ≡ [ x ] →
  ∃[ a ] (s-execute e2 (a ∷ stack) ≡ [ x ] × s-execute (s-compile e1) [] ≡ [ a ])

add-to-stack : ∀ {e2 stack x} e1 →
  s-execute (s-compile e1) [] ≡ [ x ] →
  s-execute (s-compile e1 ++ e2) stack ≡ s-execute e2 (x ∷ stack)

remove-from-stack (ANum n) prf = n , (prf , refl)
remove-from-stack {rest} {stack} (APlus e1 e2) prf with subst (λ l → s-execute l stack ≡ _) (++-assoc⁴ (s-compile e1) (s-compile e2) [ _ ]  rest) prf
... | []∷stack with remove-from-stack e1 []∷stack
remove-from-stack {rest} {stack} (APlus e1 e2) _ | []∷stack | a , a∷stack , e1≡a with remove-from-stack e2 a∷stack
remove-from-stack {rest} {stack} (APlus e1 e2) _ | []∷stack | a , a∷stack , e1≡a | b , b∷a∷stack , e2≡b = a + b , b∷a∷stack , e1+e1≡a+b where
  e1+e1≡a+b : _
  e1+e1≡a+b =
    begin
      s-execute (s-compile e1 ++ s-compile e2 ++ SPlus ∷ []) []
    ≡⟨ add-to-stack e1 e1≡a ⟩
      s-execute (s-compile e2 ++ SPlus ∷ []) [ a ]
    ≡⟨ add-to-stack e2 e2≡b ⟩
      s-execute (SPlus ∷ []) (b ∷ [ a ])
    ≡⟨⟩
      (a + b ∷ [])
    ∎

add-to-stack (ANum n) refl = refl
add-to-stack (APlus e1 e2) []∷[] with remove-from-stack e1 []∷[]
add-to-stack (APlus e1 e2) []∷[] | a , a∷[] , e1≡a with remove-from-stack e2 a∷[]
add-to-stack {rest} {stack} (APlus e1 e2) []∷[] | a , a∷[] , e1≡a | b , refl , e2≡b =
  begin
    s-execute ((s-compile e1 ++ s-compile e2 ++ SPlus ∷ []) ++ rest) stack
  ≡⟨ cong (λ l → s-execute l stack) (++-assoc⁴ (s-compile e1) (s-compile e2) [ _ ]  rest) ⟩
    s-execute (s-compile e1 ++ s-compile e2 ++ SPlus ∷ [] ++ rest) stack
  ≡⟨ add-to-stack e1 e1≡a ⟩
    s-execute (s-compile e2 ++ SPlus ∷ [] ++ rest) (a ∷ stack)
  ≡⟨ add-to-stack e2 e2≡b ⟩
    s-execute rest (a + b ∷ stack)
  ∎

s-compile-correct : (e : Aexp) → s-execute (s-compile e) [] ≡ [ aeval e ]
s-compile-correct (ANum n) = refl
s-compile-correct (APlus l r) =
  begin
    (s-execute (s-compile l ++ s-compile r ++ SPlus ∷ []) [])
  ≡⟨ add-to-stack l (s-compile-correct l) ⟩
    (s-execute (s-compile r ++ SPlus ∷ []) (aeval l ∷ []))
  ≡⟨ add-to-stack r (s-compile-correct r) ⟩
    (s-execute (SPlus ∷ []) (aeval r ∷ aeval l ∷ []))
  ≡⟨⟩
    (aeval l + aeval r ∷ [])
  ∎
```

Comment: Added the concrete example.

Comment: Since all (mutually) recursive calls are structurally decreasing on `e1`, I think you can combine both theorems (in Coq) to roughly `forall e1 e2 stack x, (remove-from-stack) /\ (add-to-stack).` and start its proof by `induction e1`. Side note: I know this problem, and you can avoid mutual recursion if you use a different approach.

Comment: Combining the two theorems did occur to me, but it is a bit awkward. Here it came out like this, but I am not sure that the same argument will be decreasing for all the problems that might require mutual recursion. Also, by another approach do you mean something else apart from this? I thought about it a lot, but I could not figure out anything.

Comment: I don't know a general way to handle mutually recursive theorems either. If such a theorem involves mutually recursive datatypes or functions, I'd suggest looking into [Equations plugin](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/), but your case doesn't seem to fit here.

Comment: The "another approach" is to generalize the theorem itself to enable induction, e.g. `forall e stack, s_execute (s_compile e) stack = aeval e :: stack`.

Comment: I don't see why you would need mutual recursion in this particular case. You can see [here](https://x80.org/collacoq/azunuyiyiw.coq) for a proof that it compiles correctly.

Comment: @Iarsr Wow, that definitely beats my own solution by quite a lot. I actually had a proof for `forall e st stack op l, s_execute st stack (s_compile e ++ op) = l -> exists a, s_execute st (a :: stack) op = l`, and I knew it did not require mutual recursion, but for some reason I did not think that removing the existential would be possible. It was a step too many for me. I guess I was too conservative in my reasoning. Thank you for the lesson.

Comment: @Iarsr Oh yeah, I cannot find `rewrite <-?` in the documentation anywhere. Is the `?` in `<-?` supposed to act as `repeat`?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic The answer is in the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.rewrite) of `rewrite`. `<-` and `?` must be taken separately. `<-` means from right to left. `?` means as many times as possible (and possibly zero time). `!` is similar, except it requires at least one rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, I don't know a general way to handle mutually recursive theorems, but (from my shallow experience) I didn't have any need to have a set of mutually recursive theorems unless they involve mutually recursive data types or functions (in which case, I suggest [Equations plugin](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/)).

This answer focuses on the specific problem.

---

The problem is very close to the last exercise of [Induction Exercises](http://jamesrwilcox.com/InductionExercises.html), except that the program halts when the Plus instruction is given too few arguments (which makes the problem slightly harder).

We start with the definitions by [@larsr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506794/how-to-do-theorems-that-require-mutual-recursion#comment99620082_56506794):

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive Sinstr : Set := SPush (_:nat) | SPlus.
Inductive Aexp : Set := ANum (_:nat) | APlus (_ _:Aexp).

Fixpoint sexec (p:list Sinstr) (s:list nat) : list nat :=
  match (p, s) with
  | ([], stack) => stack
  | ((SPush x)::prog, stack) => sexec prog (x::stack)
  | (Splus::prog, x1::x2::stack)  =>  sexec prog (x1+x2::stack)
  | (_, stack) => stack
  end.

Fixpoint aeval (a:Aexp) : nat :=
  match a with
  | ANum n => n
  | APlus a1 a2 => aeval a2 + aeval a1
  end.

Fixpoint compile (a:Aexp) : list Sinstr :=
  match a with
  | ANum n => [SPush n]
  | APlus a1 a2 => compile a1 ++ compile a2 ++ [SPlus] 
  end.
```

First, we try proof by induction directly:

```
Theorem compile_correct_try e : sexec (compile e) [] = [aeval e].
Proof.
  induction e; intros; auto. (* base case is easy *)
  simpl.

e1, e2 : Aexp
IHe1 : sexec (compile e1) [] = [aeval e1]
IHe2 : sexec (compile e2) [] = [aeval e2]
____________________________________________
sexec (compile e1 ++ compile e2 ++ [SPlus]) [] = [aeval e2 + aeval e1]
```

We're stuck at this point. We can make some observations though:

- We need a lemma that involves concatenation of two programs (obviously).
- We also need a lemma that applies to any initial stack (since `compile e2` will run on the stack `[aeval e1]`, not `[]`).

So we try writing a general lemma:

```
Lemma prg_concat :
  forall p1 p2 stack, sexec (p1 ++ p2) stack = sexec p2 (sexec p1 stack).
```

But this is simply wrong because `p2` should not run if `p1` was aborted. Then we should ensure that `p1` does not abort. One might want to define "runs to completion" prop, but we have an obvious special case that works: `compile e`. And it fits perfectly to our inductive case, because the left operands to `++` are of the form `compile _`:

```
sexec (compile e1 ++ compile e2 ++ [SPlus]) stack
->
sexec (compile e2 ++ [SPlus]) (sexec (compile e1) stack)
->
sexec [SPlus] (sexec (compile e2) (sexec (compile e1) stack))
```

The corresponding statement is:

```
Lemma compile_concat :
  forall e p s, sexec (compile e ++ p) s = sexec p (sexec (compile e) s).
```

But this is still not enough, because there is no guarantee that the final `SPlus` will succeed. So we incorporate the main goal `sexec (compile e) = [aeval e]` into the lemma, i.e. instead of `sexec (compile e) s`, we write `aeval e :: s`. Now we can guarantee that there will be at least two elements on the stack when we arrive at the final `SPlus`.

So here comes larsr's lemma:

```
Lemma compile_ok (e:Aexp): 
  forall p s, sexec (compile e ++ p) s = sexec p (aeval e::s).
Proof.
  induction e.
  reflexivity.
  intros; simpl;
    rewrite <-? app_assoc, IHe1, IHe2; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

---

Also, [here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.rewrite) is a documentation of `rewrite <-? expr`, at the end of section `rewrite`:

> Orientation `->` or `<-` can be inserted before each term to rewrite.
>
> In all forms of rewrite described above, a term to rewrite can be immediately prefixed by one of the following modifiers:
>
> - `?`: the tactic `rewrite ?term` performs the rewrite of term as many times as possible (perhaps zero time). This form never fails.

So `rewrite <-? app_assoc, IHe1, IHe2.` means to repeat (reverse) rewriting by `app_assoc`, and then (forward) rewrite by `IHe1` and `IHe2` once each.

Comment: I like this kind of answers that explain how to deduce a working proof from a stuck one.